# Наиболее оптимальный подход к проверке состояния объекта

Tags: c#, ооп, оптимизация

Давайте для начала представим подобный класс:

```
public class Vasya
{
    public void FreezeWater() => ...

    public void WalkOnWater() => ...
}
```

То есть наш `Vasya` может заморозить воду, а также может попробовать по ней пройтись. Сложного в хождении по льду нет ничего, так что подобный гипотетический код:

```
var vasya = new Vasya();
vasya.FreezeWater();
vasya.WalkOnWater();
```

выполнится без проблем, но следующий блок:

```
var vasya = new Vasya();
vasya.WalkOnWater();
```

выкинул бы нам какой-нибудь `VasyaDrownedException`, так как `Vasya` не привел воду в пригодное для прогулок агрегатное состояние

Так как настолько скоропостижно прощаться с Васей мы не хотим, мы можем подлатать класс вот так:

```
public class Vasya
{
    public bool IsWaterFrozen{ get; private set; } = false;

    public void FreezeWater() 
    {
        IsWaterFrozen = true;
        ...
    }

    public void WalkOnWater() 
    {
        if (!IsWaterFrozen)
            throw new InvalidActionException("Water is not frozen!");
        ...
    }
}
```

В таком случае отъявленная попытка утопить Васю выбросит уже ожидаемое нами исключение, так что на этом можно было бы и закончить, но вот беда: наш Вася - объект весьма азартный, так что пробежки по воде он совершает, скажем, *тысячи раз в секунду*. Таким образом мы имеем тысячу *лишних* проверок и тысячу же гипотетических исключений (а проброс исключения, как мы знаем, - операция не из дешевых) в секунду

Подобное положение дел для метода, который так часто вызывают (так что его производительность критична), мне кажется неприемлемым

В теории, можно поправить ситуацию подобным образом:

```
public class Vasya
{
    public bool IsWaterFrozen{ get; private set; } = false;
    private Action _walkOnWater ;

    public Vasya() => _walkOnWater = ThrowWaterIsNotFrozen;

    public void FreezeWater() 
    {
        _walkOnWater = SuccessfullyWalkOnWater;
        IsWaterFrozen = true;
        ...
    }

    public void WalkOnWater() => _walkOnWater();

    private void ThrowWaterIsNotFrozen() => throw new InvalidActionException("Water is not frozen!");

    private void SuccessfullyWalkOnWater() => ...
}
```

То есть мы избавляем метод от постоянных проверок, единственный раз поменяв контекст вызова

Но тут у меня возникает еще один вопрос:
Не будет ли дополнительный вызов делегата более накладным, нежели проверка булевого флага?

---

В общем, если подводить черту, то вопрос таков: как **правильнее** будет организовать вызов метода, логика которого *зависит от вызова иного метода*, а также чья *производительность* для нас очень и очень *критична*

Comment: И простите, пожалуйста, за такой больной пример хД

Comment: Эээ, ну сделайте бенчмарки... А вообще, имхо, всё это может зависеть от реализации платформы, компилятора, железа и прочего. Есть же всякие предсказатели переходов и т. п.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: это понятно, просто хотелось бы услышать мнение людей, которые уже сталкивались с подобной проблемой ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АндрейNOP: судя по бенчмаркам, вариант с делегатами все таки хуже. Но утверждать это сложно, ибо отклонение между методами вписывается в допустимую ошибку измерения ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну в общем-то я так и предлагал, операция "разыменования" делегата ни чуть не лучше чем условная операция, наверняка там еще и какие-то дополнительные проверки навешаны. Ну и предсказатель переходов я не зря упомянул

Comment: _имеем ... тысячу же гипотетических исключений ... в секунду_ - c чего бы? Исключение будет выброшено одно-единственное, после чего Вася никуда не бежит, а медленно погружается в пучину...

Comment: Вообще, в реальном приложении Вася будет выполнять кучу проверок на каждом ходу: не уперся ли он в стену, не завяз ли в болоте, не наступил ли на гвоздь и т. п. То есть добавление ещё одной проверки `!_isWaterFrozen` не станет чем-то критичным.

Comment: Вот ещё что: вода замораживается сразу везде, во всём мире? Или только на некотором расстоянии от Васи? А может ли она разморозиться спустя некоторое время?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: *после чего Вася никуда не бежит, а медленно погружается в пучину* - ну, это да. Не совсем точно выразил свою мысль: метод каждую итерацию может выкинуть ошибку, это заложено в нем, хотя после заморозки даже и проверять не стоит, а надо ли выбрасывать исключение

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: *вода замораживается сразу везде, во всём мире* - это абстрактный пример, демонстрирующий смену некого состояния, от которого зависит логика дальнейшей работы. Так что в контексте данного вопроса можно сказать, что да, во всем мире, а также никогда не будет раморожена

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фактически к вашему случаю можно применить `State pattern`.

Создаем интерфейс типа состояния Васи

```
public interface IVasyaState
{
    IVasyaState FreezeWater();
    IVasyaState WalkOnWater(Action addSteps);
}
```

Теперь реализуем этот интерфейс в двух классах "вода не заморожена" и "вода заморожена".

```
public class NotFreezedWater : IVasyaState
{
    //меняем состояние на заморож.воду
    public IVasyaState FreezeWater() => new FreezedWater();

    //шаги не прибавляем, просто возвращаем текущее сост.
    public IVasyaState WalkOnWater(Action addSteps) => this;
}

public class FreezedWater : IVasyaState
{
    //ничего не делаем
    public IVasyaState FreezeWater() => this;

    public IVasyaState WalkOnWater(Action addSteps)
    {
        addSteps();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Ну, а теперь собственно сам Вася

```
public class Vasya
{
    //ctor
    public Vasya()
    {
        State = new NotFreezedWater();
    }

    //состояние Васи
    public IVasyaState State { get; set; }

    //количество проделанных шагов
    public int CountSteps { get; private set; }

    public void FreezeWater()
    {
        State = State.FreezeWater();
    }

    public void WalkOnWater(int steps)
    {
        State = State.WalkOnWater(() => { this.CountSteps += steps; });
    }
}
```

Несомненный плюс этого паттерна в том, что не нужно плодить кучу if() на проверку разнообразных условий на значения свойств объекта и соблюдение принципа единственности ответственности тоже никто не отменял. Да, и не надо никаких эксепшенов выбрасывать и проч.

Сам пример с тестами [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/VasiaState).

Comment: Чудесная идея! Так код станет проще, а в производительности он пострадать не должен (как я уже писал в комменатриях, вызов дополнительного метода не сказывается (или сказывается незначительно) на времени выполнения). Подойду к решению вопроса именно таким образом, так что помечу ответом, спасибо)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Всегда, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тоже не знаю, правильно ли я понял вопрос, отвечу так как понял.

Тут, как мне видится, три варианта:

1. Эти два метода не могут вызываться по отдельности и действуют в жесткой связке (Вася всегда замораживает воду перед тем как по ней погулять)
2. Второй метод не может быть вызван без первого (Вася может заморозить воду от нечего делать, но если собирается по ней гулять, то не забывает об этом)
3. Оба метода могут быть вызваны отдельно друг от друга (Вася морозит воду когда ему вздумается и гуляет несмотря ни на что)

В первом случае инкапсулируем их в третий метод, который всегда вызывает их в правильном порядке. В этом случае никаких проверок не требуется и исключения не возникают

```
public class Vasya
{
        private void FreezeWater() { }


        private void WalkOnWater() { }


        public void MakeMove()
        {
            FreezeWater();
            WalkOnWater();
        }
}
```

Соответственно, если мы хотим, чтобы Вася нагулялся, то

```
public class Vasya
{
        private void FreezeWater() { }


        private void WalkOnWater() { }


        public void MakeMove()
        {
            FreezeWater();
            WalkOnWater();
        }

        public void Walk()
        {
            FreezeWater();
            for(int step = 0; step < 1000; step++)
            { 
                WalkOnWater();
            }
        }
}
```

Во втором случае оставляем первый метод открытым, все остальное остается как в первом варианте

```
 public class Vasya
 {
        public void FreezeWater() { }


        private void WalkOnWater() { }


        public void MakeMove()
        {
            FreezeWater();
            WalkOnWater();
        }
  }
```

В третьем случае мы ожидаем, что второй метод может быть вызван без предварительно вызванного первого. Довольно странно разрешить Васе гулять, когда он захочет, и ругать его, если вода перед этим не была заморожена. Поэтому генерация исключений в этом случае мне представляется неверной. Мы ожидаем, что он может гулять, не заморозив воду, и, следовательно, должны обработать эту ситуацию как нормальную, а не как исключительную. В ответе @Andrew показан один из вариантов решения. Вася может гулять когда захочет и сам принимает решение пойдет он или не пойдет.

Можно пойти дальше и избавиться от проверки условия заморожена ли вода каждый раз, когда Вася делает новый шаг, реализовав паттерн Состояние для воды или Стратегия для Васи. Например, стратегия для Васи

```
public class Vasya
{
    publicvoid FreezeWater() 
    {
        ...
        movingStrategy = new FrozenWaterMovingStrategy();
    }

    public MovingStrategy movingStrategy = new LiquidWaterMovingStrategy();

    public void WalkOnWater()
    {
        movingStrategy.Move();
    }
}

public abstract class MovingStrategy
{
    public abstract void Move();
}

public class FrozenWaterMovingStrategy : MovingStrategy
{

    public override void Move()
    {
        // то что было в теле метода WalkOnWater()
    }
}

public class LiquidWaterMovingStrategy : MovingStrategy
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        // обработка ожидаемого поведения Васи в жидкой воде
    }
}
```

При всей азартности Васи нужный метод будет вызываться без всяких проверок

Comment: Смотрите, по поводу первых двух вариантов вариантов: Вася может повторно гулять по замороженной воде, нет необходимости замораживать ее вновь, так что метод `MakeMove` не совсем подходит к общей логике. По поводу третьего метода: очень хорошая идея!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, согласен, в таком случае он не годится, но если заранее известно количество вызовов второго метода, то можно использовать метод `Walk()`, в котором один раз вызывается заморозка, а потом делается некоторое количество шагов. Если количество вызовов неизвестно, то от проверки заморожена ли вода, наверное, никуда не деться. В случае Состояния или Стратегии, в котором этой проверки нет, есть свой неприятный эффект: необходимо реализовывать логику движения по жидкой воде, что в некоторых задачах не всегда возможно, к сожалению.

Comment: Кстати о `Walk`:  `100` стоит не хардкодить, а передавать в качестве параметра. А по поводу *логики хождения по жидкой воде*: ее нет, мы просто замораживаем воду, меняем состояние и заново вызываем метод хождения, который отработает теперь уже в другом состоянии.

Answer (score 1):

Хз, на сколько я понял вопрос...

Но мне кажется что вот это будет самым быстрым вариантом

```
public class Vasya
{
    private _isWaterFrozen = true;

    public void FreezeWater() 
    {
        _isWaterFrozen = true;
        ...
    }

    public bool WalkOnWater() 
    {
        if (!_isWaterFrozen)
            return false;
        ...
        ...
        ... 
        return true;
    }
}
```

возвращение флага методом в любом случае быстрее чем ексепшн, использование делегата или, недай боже, tryCatch-а где-то извне

Comment: Согласен, возврат булевого флага (через `return` или `out`) куда безопаснее и быстрее проброса исключения, так что да, вариант хороший. Однако в общем случае, когда у нас много методов, которые должны изменять свою логику в зависимости от ситуации, мне больше нравится идея с машиной состояний в ответе **Bulson**: это упраздняет множественные проверки и в принципе сделает код чище) Но спасибо за Ваш ответ!)